# Filling a RichEmbed with a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For my Discord bot, I am fetching data (json) from an API. I am looping with `a for` loop through all the json data and want to use [`.addfield()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=addField) for every piece of data found. Unfortunately, this is not working. How I could fix this?

This is my current code:

```
let search = json.search
let richembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("Title")
  .setDescription("Description")
  for (i in search) {
    let title = search[i].title
    let snippet = search[i].snippet
    .addField(title, snippet)
  }
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter("bot.user.username", bot.user.avatarURL)
```

This is an example JSON response from the API.

```json
"search": [{
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Monkey",
    "snippet": "text here",
    "timestamp": "2019-03-19T04:18:52Z"
  },
  {
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "The Monkey",
    "snippet": "text here",
    "timestamp": "2018-12-31T14:40:16Z"
  },
  {
    "ns": 0,
    "title": "Monkey see, monkey do",
    "snippet": "text here",
    "timestamp": "2019-01-16T00:12:51Z"
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do a for loop in a RichEmbed Builder. You have to do it like in the following code:

```js
let search = json.search    
let richembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setDescription("Description")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter("bot.user.username", bot.user.avatarURL);

for (i of search) {
  let title = i.title
  let snippet = i.snippet
  richembed.addField(title, snippet)
}
```

Comment: Since `search` is an array, I would use directly `for (let item of search) {...}`. If you're using ES6, you can also write `let {title, snippet} = item; richembed.addField(title, snippet)`

Comment: Thanks! You mean like I edited it now? @FedericoGrandi

Comment: Exactly: that makes it way easier if you just need the object and not the index itself ;)